Big query Update error: Update set does not support array modification with []
I am trying to update a field that is structure type but I have This error:
Update set does not support array modification with []
I tried This sql code in big query:
update `mytablelocation` 
set
  event_params[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].value.string_value = SHA256( event_params[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].value.string_value) 
where
  event_name = 'purchase' 
  and
  event_params[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].key = 'email'

To transform an email value tô hash sha256

I think you cannot update only an array element, you need to update the entire array.

I fully agree with Mr Martins.  You should contemplate how to set the field event_params rather than try and update an element in it.  I'd suggest updating your question with the schema of the table and some sample data.
